# EF Core Automated Migration Flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, database-migration

So what I am trying to do, is to build a kinda automated flow of migrations for the development environment, as mentioned in the title. I don't like the principle, that you have to execute `dotnet ef migrations add <migration>` every time you have some changes, that you need on your database, and I am building a huge project with a few mates, so I need that. I hope someone can help me here.

#### Steps of how it is supposed to work

1. Start running or rerunning the project
2. The user will be prompted in the terminal, to enter within 3 seconds 'y'or 'n' for adding a new migration (if no was chosen, or the timeout was reached, the project will just start normally)
3. The user entered 'y', he will be prompted to enter a migration name
4. A migration file will be generated using ef core
5. The project applies the new generated migration to the database

#### How it is currently working

1. Step 1 to 4 are operational, and I am satisfied with that
2. Step 5 is not applying the migration to the database on the same project startup as mentioned in the steps above, to apply the migrations, I have to actually give the project a second restart/rerun, so it applies it.

#### Relevant code snippets:

At **Startup.cs**, I have the following tasks in the following order:

**These tasks where implemented, according to [this](https://laptrinhx.com/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-part-2-1924964588/) article**

```
if (_env.IsDevelopment()) 
            services.AddStartupTask<MigrationWizardStartupTask>();
        services.AddStartupTask<MigrationStartupTask>();
```

The **MigrationWizardStartupTask** contains the following relevant part:

```
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nMigration or change name (camel case, no spaces input): ");
                    migrationName = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (migrationName?.TrimEmptyToNull() == null || migrationName.Split(" ").Length > 1)
                    {
                        _restartWizard = true;
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "Incorrect input, please enter the name with no spaces and try again....");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _restartWizard = false;
                    }
                } while (_restartWizard);

                _logger.LogInformation("Creating migration....");

                var migrationTask = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        Tercmd.DotnetBuilder.Create(baseDir.MigrationsPathFromRoot())
                            .AddMigration(migrationName, 5000);
                    });
                migrationTask.Start();
                migrationTask.Wait();
```

and the **AddMigration** method basically executes the command with a thread sleep:

```
               var proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                    {
                        WorkingDirectory = _directory, FileName = TerminalKeys.Dotnet.ToLowerString(),
                        Arguments = $"ef migrations add {migrationName}",
                        CreateNoWindow = false
                    }
                };
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
```

The second task is the **MigrationStartupTask** which should always run, and basically only migrates the database.

```
                _logger.LogInformation("Initializing Db connection....");
                var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
                var pendingMigrations = await db.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync();
                var pendingMigrationsCount = pendingMigrations.Count();
                _logger.LogInformation("Starting Migrations, migrations pending: {0}", pendingMigrationsCount);
                await db.Database.MigrateAsync();
```

So it seems that it is probably already migrating the database, without having the generated file ready. That is my thought, but I can't figure out where the problem is, and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!!